# Switch pages without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

My Electron App has an Menu in the every `.html` Page witch is controlled by an `controller.js`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  const app = require("electron").remote.app;
  const { remote } = require("electron");

  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    window.location = "index.html";
  });

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    window.location = "aaa.html";
  });

  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    window.location = "bbb.html";
  });

  $("#btn4").click(function() {
    window.location = "ccc.html";
  });
  $("#btn5").click(function() {
    window.location = "ddd.html";
  });

  $("#btn6").click(function() {
    window.location = "eee.html";
  });

  $("#btn7").click(function() {
    window.location = "fff.html";
  });
});
```

In the every Html Page i have in the head section  so the controller.js can work! My question now is how to make this without to reload all the time the window when switching the page?

For example When I go to aaa.html It feels like in the Browser a have for a few Milliseconds a White screen then it goes to the new Page, How I can make this work without White Window when Clicking a Button to go to a new Page? I want the Content to be loaded when I click the Button without this Browser feeling.

Any Ideas how I can do this or what I can do better here? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question technically : you could get the content of your pages using the **fetch API**, and then parse them using a **DOMParser** and then replace the current content of your page (or just a part of it, say not the header and footer, but everything else) with what you just parsed, using the **history API**

Making this all work nicely together is not straightforward though, and you will never get rid of some level of rendering 'flashes' in some places in most cases.

What you probably want to build is a **single page application**, I suggest you check out **React, Vue or Angular** and build from those

---

Edit :

An other solution is to **load everything upfront and then inject/remove elements using javascript**, for this solution, I would recommend using **templates** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: Thank you for the info but I wanted to do a single page application only with JavaScript without using a Framework is this possible?

Comment: You have 3 options here

Comment: 1 • You could use an iframe, but it does not feel right to me

Comment: 2 • You could load everything upfront and inject/remove html from you page, in which case I recommend using templates (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: 3 • Or you could build your own framework, which is hard, let's be honest, and not really a solution, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Besides solving the page request problem, i would advise to adopt available frameworks and libraries that support in building single page applications. A lot of work has already been done for you.

Personally i would use React with the react-router package to create an SPA. If you want to reduce flashes between transitions, you need to avoid re-rendering the whole page. This is exactly what UI libraries like React do.